# Javascript calls from partial views to main view

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-partialview

Alright, so I have a JQuery Grid loaded in a partial view in asp.net mvc. So, let's say that on that partial view, I am able to get the row that is selected in my JQGrid. However, let's say that the main view that loaded the partial view cannot access that directly, since the main view loaded on the browser refresh and the partial view was loaded using ajax. Now, what's the best way to go about doing this. Should I use JSON to store I guess the state of the application. So, in this case, I want to be able to access javascript or elements of the partial view from the main view.

What is the best way to go about doing this?

Answer (score 0):

I have found that keeping my state in a JSON object on the client is much easier than trying to coordinate everything server-side, especially when using dynamically loaded partial views. This allows you to determine what changes and or functions are necessary on the client side, and then get from the server specifically what is needed.

Another nifty thing I use is knockout.js. It keeps your UI state consistent with your client-side object. It may or may not work with the grid you're using, but I have found that it simplifies change tracking and makes my code much easier to maintain.